# Javascript argument in function

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble passing an array as an argument of a function:

```
function test() {
   var array1 = ["1","2"];
   var show = "<p>Show: <a href=# onClick='showArray("+array1+")'>Click to show array</a></p>";
}
```

So I need to have an onClick as it is there, but when I pass an array and call the function

```
function showArray(array) { alert (array.length); }
```

Returns nothing. Why not work?

EDIT:

```
function test() {
    var array1 = [];
    array1[0] = {
        "type" : 0, 
        "message" : "example", 
        "from" : "path1",
        "count" : 1,
        "isChecked": false
    };
    array1[1] = {
        "type" : 2, 
        "message" : "example", 
        "from" : "path2",
        "count" : 50,
        "isChecked": false
    };

   var show = "<p>Show: <a href=# onClick='showArray(["+array1+"])'>Click to show array</a></p>";
}
```

Comment: Do you want the click event to call `showArray(array1)` such that the function uses the contents of the `array1` variable at the time the event occurs? Or do you want the click event to call `showArray(["1","2"])` such that the function uses the array values as they were at the time the element was created (ignoring any changes to the `array1` variable that may have happened since)?

Comment: In that case take a look at Mark Linus's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is not working because the evaluated value of the `show` var is the following:

```
"<p>Show: <a href=# onClick='showArray(\"1\",\"2\")'>Click to show array</a></p>"
```

Which means that the `showArray` function is receiving two parameters ("1" and "2") and neither of them is an array, but a string.

To make your code work, use this:

```
var show = "<p>Show: <a href=# onClick='showArray(["+array1+"])'>Click to show array</a></p>"
```

By this way, the evaluated value will be:

```
"<p>Show: <a href=# onClick='showArray([\"1\",\"2\"])'>Click to show array</a></p>"
```

Which means that `showArray` will receive only one parameter: the ["1","2"] array

Comment: Actually besides that problem, he is calling the method showArray, and the function is being declared as show.

Comment: That's interessing. But if I have "var array1 = []; array1[0] = { "type" : 0 }; array1[1] = { "type" : 2 };" the code does not work. Why?

Comment: Well, please post the code you're now trying to use and then I'll answer your question

Comment: See my changes in the main post. That structure is that I get to the array. And thank you!

Comment: Can you show the jsFiddle please? There is no error, it does not alert to the size of the array.

Comment: Now I got this error. It`s happening because, with this declaration, array1 is being concatenated with the whole string. But the problem is that this is an array of objects, so when passed to a string it turns (int this case) to [Object,Object], so it loses its properties. In this case, the best to do is to use Nadav's code ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ckfVY/))

Answer (score 1):

Everyone is missing it:

```
var show = "<p>Show: <a href='javascript:showArray(array1)'>Click to show array</a></p>"
```

1. You have to take out the quotes if you use a variable.
2. The "href" attribute didn't contain quotes.
3. It is recommended to use `href="javascript:"` instead of `onclick`

Comment: _'It is recommended to use_ `href="javascript:"` _instead of_ `onclick`' - recommended by whom? The usual recommendation is the opposite.

Comment: You know what? Maybe. But every link must contain the `href` attribute, so why add `onclick` and put `#` in `href`? You can do everything in one place.

Comment: Yes I forgot to write. I'm trying to test your solutions.

Comment: Either way will work. I prefer to set the `href` to an actual valid url so that for users with JS disabled they still get some functionality (even if the url just takes them to an error page that says "Please enable JavaScript to use this site.").

Comment: @nnnnnn that's interesting. I will think about it in the future. But think about what will happen when users click a link that doesn't function at all.

Comment: @NadavS. Google [does not recommend](http://code.google.com/intl/zh-TW/edu/submissions/html-css-javascript/#javascript) putting JavaScript in either `href` or `onclick`.

Comment: If the `href` contains a valid url the link will always function, at worst becoming a backup for broken JS. In your JS event handler (whether assigned via an `onclick` attribute or with `addEventListener()`) you then cancel the default action of the event so that the user isn't taken to the url when they have JS enabled.

Comment: Yeah maybe you're right. At least for now, I guess all the browsers in the world support JS. But I will think about that. And how do you explain that Facebook is using `javascript:` too?

Comment: Browsers support JS, but a (very) small percentage of _users_ have it disabled. Some corporate and government sites have JS disabled for all their users whether the users like it or not.

Answer (score 0):

Take out the quotes:

```
var show = "<p>Show: <a href=# onClick='showArray(array1)'>Click to show array</a></p>";
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<script>
var array1 = ["1","2"];
function showArray(myArray) { alert (myArray.length); } 
</script>
<p>Show: <a href='#' onClick='showArray(array1); return false;'>Click to show array</a></p>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

and here is a link to this example: http://jsfiddle.net/eNXx5/

Answer (score 0):

Your onclick calls `showArray` but your function is called `show`.

If you inspect the DOM, you'll see what the JS is creating:

```
<a href="#" onclick="showArray(1,2)">Click to show array</a>
```

That's not valid! So just change it to

```
<a href='#' onClick='showArray(array1)'>
```

and the DOM will be exactly that, as well. This is valid.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/BPNq6/)